# Проблема с обновлением чата

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap4, smarty

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть ошибка? Это чат, сообщения чата всегда внизу и обновляются при отправке, но скролл почему-то постоянно через несколько секунд в середину переходит

````
<script>
var element = document.getElementById("shout_block");
setInterval(function(){
  if (element.scrollTop == 480) {
        element.scrollTop = 1400;
    }
}, 10);
// автопрокрутка вниз сообщений
function vniz(){
    $("div.shout_block").animate({"scrollTop":1400},"slow");
}
function checkvniz() {
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
}
 function ajax_shout() {
    if ( CHatDoc.readyState != 4 ) return ;
        //ответ сервера в виде обычного текста
        var docTEXT = CHatDoc.responseText;
        //создаем элемент div
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        //добавляем ответ сервера в div
        div.innerHTML = docTEXT;
        //добавляем div с ответом сервера в дерево документа, т.е. в DOM
        document.getElementById("shout_block").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("shout_block").appendChild(div);
    }
    
     var CHatDoc = null ;
 
     function update_shout()
     {      
        setTimeout("update_function_shout()", {/literal}{$update_shout}{literal});
        if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != 'undefined' ) {
          CHatDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          CHatDoc.onreadystatechange = ajax_shout ;
        }
        else {
          CHatDoc = new XMLHttpRequest();
          CHatDoc.onload = ajax_shout ;
        }   
        //alert(1);
        CHatDoc.open( "GET", "/ajax_page/ajax_shout.php", true );
        CHatDoc.send( null ); 
        }
        
                
setTimeout("update_function_shout()", {/literal}{$update_shout}{literal});
function update_function_shout(){
    update_shout();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    vniz();
});
</script>
{/literal}```
````

Comment: Что за магическое число `1400`?

Comment: Если ставлю меньше он скролл вверх ставит

Comment: Наверное, надо высчитывать значение для `scrollTop` каждый раз на основе `scrollHeight`.